# Options to re-encode video with new key frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I need to add key frames at 2 second intervals in this video.

```
ffprobe input-video.mp4 
ffprobe version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-11-23T10:04:47.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:00.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16302 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 16174 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-11-23T10:04:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-11-23T10:04:47.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

I used this ffmpeg command for this purpose.

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -r 23.976 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -c:a copy -y output.mp4
```

However, this output.mp4 now has different video bitrate (3692 kb/s) compared to the original video (16302 kb/s). How do I use the ffmpeg command to re-encode the video with key frames and **with the same bitrate as original video**?

Comment: You're re-encoding the video, so the original bitrate isn't all that relevant to the encoder because it's encoding raw frames.  Just set `-b:v` as you wish.

Comment: do 2-pass encoding with `-b:v` option or play with `-crf` option in 1-pass to get it close. See [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)